# First Parameter in Mysqli functions

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm starting to transition towards Mysqli on my website project and am noticing that for several different functions such as `mysqli_query` or `mysqli_select_db` it is requiring the first parameter to be `$link`, `$link` being `mysqli_connect()`.

Is this necessary for every function? If I leave out the parameter can I expect the function to go to the default `mysqli_connect()` I put at the beginning of my code?

Comment: Does the manual not describe this? (Edit: `$link` is indeed not an optional argument in procedural style. What style are you using?)

Comment: Procedural. I must have misread the manual/ assumed there was a caveat that did not exist. Thanks for the help.

Comment: With the `mysql_*` functions the `$link` was often optional, but not with `mysqli_*` if you use the procedural interface. You need that link, it's often the first parameter then.

Comment: Yeah, it's different from `mysql_query` where the link identifier is optional and the last one opened is used when none is specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only required if you use the procedural interface.

If you are using the object oriented interface it isn't necessary because all of your calls use the `$mysqli` object to call functions.

See [Dual procedural and object-oriented interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) for more explanation.